# DRF Read only field is still validated

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a field that I want always to be the user. My serializer is like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user',)

    def perform_save(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

But it gives me the error `NOT NULL constraint failed: app_my_model.user_id` but the field is read_only... I don't get this.

Comment: What is your underlying `Model` definition?

Comment: Edited the question with it!

Comment: I think regardless of your serialiser, `MyModel` cannot have a null value for `user`, try adding `null=True` into your `user` field and migrating

Comment: But I am passing the user in the serializer.save method. It can't be and it isn't NULL

Comment: On command line install pudb: `pip install pudb`.  Then put this line right before `serializer.save...`   ->  `import pudb; pudb.set_trace()` .

Comment: You may also try doing `serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user.id)`.  Also, does your interface allow anonymous users?  Are you sure `self.request.user` is a valid user?

Comment: Where do I get the trace? Also tried setting directly the id and still didn't work

Comment: That `set_trace()` opens a debugger.  You find its result in the window you're running `python manage.py runserver ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no method named **`perform_save()`** for a serializer, it's for the **`viewset`** class. This may be the problem 
Use the **`save()`** method as below

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user',)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```